# porting matlab code on to TI OMAP L138

Tags: matlab, electrical-signal

I have already working matlab based code for an application. i want to port on to OMAP L138 using matlab coder.  I have some queries related to this

1. Is it possible to do on a omap based custom board.?
2. Does  embedded coder support all the matlab function.
3. Is it the right way to build a communication system (i.e simulate and test in matlab then port it to dsp using matlab coder)

I think some experienced engineer advice is required here?

Comment: 1. and 2. aren't signal processing questions as at all, and 3. is incredibly broad - how should we know whether that kind of workflow is appropriate for you?

Comment: (also, I'd have to admit that with modern multiple-GHz ARMs that can do NEON and have good caching interfaces, the niche for this particular OMAP sounds *very* narrow. Are you even sure you need to use a DSP chip, at all? Can't what you want to do not be more easily done at nearly the same power efficiency on a general purpose processor? I'm almost certain that just straightforward implementing your signal processing on a quad-core 2 GHz ARM board (think: modern raspberry Pis, hardkernel's Odroids) is going to perform better: neither the MIPS nor the FLOPS of the DSP in your OMAP sound great.)

Answer (score 1):

1 - Too broad, please be more specific

2 - Most functions are supported, you can check the simulink blocks to see if they support code generation. That being said, even if a function is supported, it does not mean that it makes sense to have it in your code. You can also convert Matlab functions to C/C++ but there are restrictions.

3 - What you describe is a model-based design where your simulation model and your executable are based on the same source. I use model-based designs in power systems, I use a controller for simulations and I use the same controller for code generation.

It works well, reduces development time, helps eliminating bugs. However, it's not a silver bullet, it's not as easy as Mathworks wants you to think. You still need some coding skills.

Comment: We have already decided to go with the OMAPL138 processor. Actually my application is to build BPSK mod/demod with FEC for a data rate of maximum of 500 kbps. Should i implement my signal processing blocks in the ARM or DSP side? which is better? 2. Can i build matlab code and convert to C/C++ using matlab embedded coder and port it on to DSP. or Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I would implement the signal processing blocks on the DSP.